# heap_corruption and memory_corruption in Windows Phone 8

Tags: memory, windows-phone-8, heap-memory, heap-corruption, memory-corruption

I develop app for Windows Phone 8 and i'm testing it on device and emulator. All working great. I can't catch errors, but when i publish app to store, sometimes i get errors with these stack traces from market:

```
Error 1:

Frame    Image              Function           Offset        
0        heap_corruption    heap_corruption    0x00000000

Error 2:

Frame    Image                Function                             Offset        
0        memory_corruption    agcore                               0x00000000
```

How diagnose these errors or how fix them?! I try search in Google, but I  not find any results for this problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have any more details or even a stack trace it will be very hard to determine exactly whats happening.

There is a strong possibility that this may be some faulty device throwing this error. How many users do you have using your app and how many errors are being thrown?

Can you give us more details on your app?